# Is there a way to check which built in methods in Python work for an object?

Tags: python

When I want to look at the methods an object in Python has, I often just do

```py
dir(obj)
```

For instance,

```py
dir(list())
```

returns

```
['__add__',
 '__class__',
 '__contains__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__delitem__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__getitem__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__iadd__',
 '__imul__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__iter__',
 '__le__',
 '__len__',
 '__lt__',
 '__mul__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__reversed__',
 '__rmul__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__setitem__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 'append',
 'clear',
 'copy',
 'count',
 'extend',
 'index',
 'insert',
 'pop',
 'remove',
 'reverse',
 'sort']
```

However, I can still do

```py
max([1,2,3,4,5])
```

which returns `5`. But note `max` is not on that list.

I was wondering if there was a method for checking which built in functions accept a given object? So for instance, `max` can operate on lists. It would be nice if there were a list  of "here's all the built in functions that can operate on a list."

Comment: How would you know if a method can be called on some type or not ? Only executing it would answer it, you can do `len(123)` it'll raise an Exception, but you can still run that

Comment: `max` is a builtin global function. It's not associate with any class. `dir` gives you the attributes of an object. `max` doesn't need to be an attribute to be usable. However it does use `__le__` methods to do it's job.

Comment: You need `help(max)`.

Comment: @rdas Looks like it [doesn't](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PzknsbhYwdmKSwEIUlLTFOLjc1Lj4zWKU3PSdBTySzJSizQhkiBQlFpSWpSnEFJUmsrFlZtYoRHtrKGpowAkYjX//wcA).

Comment: @rdas `__le__` is the magic method which stands for "less or equal" (for operand <=). You probably mean `__len__`, which is used by the `len` builtin function.